# Does the Jacobi's formula work for the none positive-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The usage of the [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) lead to the following expression
$$\det(\exp A)=\exp(tr A)$$
which was a corollary of the Jacobi's formula.

However, it turned out that this formula might not be suitable(in fact, was not) for some seemingly plain calculations.
One used it during the calculation of a functional integral, which involved a skew-symmetric matrix, or a matrix of the form $\delta_{i+j}$. The above expression broke down and no longer hold.

Question:

1. (Fact check, not the point) show that the Kronecker delta $\delta_{i+j}$ ($i,j\in \mathbb{Z}$) was not a positive definite matrix.
2. Show or prove that why the Jacob's formula or $$\det(\exp A)=\exp(tr A)$$ did not work for the none positive definite matrix?

---

**The previous question**
(you don't have to answer it, because the expression was wrong, it's only attached as a record of the context.)

How to evaluate
$$tr(\log ((k_i +a)\delta_{i+j} ))$$
where $a$ some constant and $i,j\in \mathbb{Z}$ were the integer index, and the Kronecker delta $\delta_{i+j}=1$ if $i+j=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

The related question could be found [What's the matrix inverse of $A_{ij}=(k_i+a)\delta_{i+j}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305693/whats-the-matrix-inverse-of-a-ij-k-ia-delta-ij)
The answer ought to lead to a term of $\sum_{i} \log(k_i+\alpha)$ but it's been almost 20 hours and it did not appear to be so.

Comment: $\delta_{ij}$ or $\delta_{i+j}$?

Comment: @VIVID $\delta_{i+j}$ because the matrix could not be positive definite. (The question had been changed though).

Comment: The corollary is true for all $(n\times n)$ matrices. The problem is that $\exp(A)$ can be difficult to evaluate for some matrices, and taking the determinant only compounds the numerical difficulties. On the other hand, both ${\rm trace}(A)$ and the exponential of a scalar value can be calculated very robustly.

Comment: @greg It was assumed to be so, but apparently it's wrong. It did not work for all $n\times n$ matrix, but the case in the example was a matrix of the size of "very large" i.e. infinity, though. Still, it didn't work, the dependence reduced from $k_i$ to only $k_0$.

Comment: I don't understand your assertion that the corollary is "wrong". If one denotes the eigenvalues as $\lambda_k$, then the equality
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \exp(\lambda_k) \;=\; \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\right)$$
is a fundamental property of the exponential function itself.